# Добавление класса active пункту меню, соответствующему текущей странице

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Начал изучение Flask с переделки [сайта](http://koslesinform.ru/), где все страницы статические.
Теперь все шаблоны страниц будут наследоваться от основного шаблона base, в котором есть главное меню сайта:

```html
...
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li>
    <a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">Главная</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown">Услуги<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('main.projects_development') }}">Проекты освоения</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('main.forest_regulation') }}">Лесоустройство</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{{ url_for('main.contacts') }}">Контакты</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="{{ url_for('main.about_us') }}">О нас</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Вход</a></li>
</ul>
```

Столкнулся с проблемой выделения пункта меню, который соответствует активной странице, раньше класс active был добавлен вручную в самом коде, теперь же надо определять этот класс определять динамически.
Пока из идей только добавление блока if, который проверяет вхождение строки с маршрутом в значение request.url, то есть примерно так:

```html
<li {% if '/contacts' in  request.url %}class="active"{% endif %}>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это реализовать?
Как проверить это условие для маршрута '/'?
Или, вообще, это правильнее реализовать через JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В шаблонах доступна переменная `request`, содержащая [соответствующий объект Request](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request). А в этом объекте доступны `request.endpoint` и `request.view_args`, которые содержат полную информацию о том, какая вьюха сейчас работает и с какими аргументами, и можно писать что-то вроде `{% if request.endpoint == 'index' %}active{% endif %}`, не привязываясь таким образом к конкретным ссылкам и не городя лишние переменные.

Так как почти наверняка проверки окажутся длинными, есть смысл вынести всё однотипное в макрос или даже в отдельную функцию, которую потом [запхнуть в контекст Jinja2](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors). В одном из своих проектов я юзаю такую функцию:

```
from flask import request

def is_current_endpoint(endpoint, **kwargs):
    if not endpoint or endpoint != request.endpoint:  # проверяем, та ли вьюха
        return False
    if kwargs and not request.view_args:  # если переданы аргументы, проверяем и их
        return False
    for k in kwargs:
        if k not in request.view_args or request.view_args[k] != kwargs[k]:
            return False
    return True
```

Используется примерно так (целесообразно вынести в макрос):

```
<li
  class="menu{% if is_current_endpoint('index') %} active{% endif %}">
  Главная
</li>
<li
  class="menu{% if is_current_endpoint('posts_index') %} active{% endif %}">
  Посты
</li>
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}{# Объект из Flask-Login для примера #}
  <li
    class="menu{% if is_current_endpoint('profile', username=current_user.username) %} active{% endif %}">
    Мой профиль
  </li>
{% endif %}
<li
  class="menu{% if is_current_endpoint('profile', username='admin') %} active{% endif %}">
  Профиль админа :)
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так (может кому пригодится, кто-то предложит другой вариант или поправит):

***base.html***

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li {% block index %}{% endblock %}>
        <a href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}">
            Главная
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown {% block services %}{% endblock %}">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
           data-toggle="dropdown">
            Услуги<b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for('main.projects_development') }}">Проекты освоения</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('main.forest_regulation') }}">Лесоустройство</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li {% block contacts %}{% endblock %}>
        <a href="{{ url_for('main.contacts') }}">
            Контакты
        </a>
    </li>
    <li {% block about_us %}{% endblock %}>
        <a href="{{ url_for('main.about_us') }}">О нас</a>
    </li>
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}">Выход</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Вход</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

***index.html***

```html
{%- extends 'base.html' %}
...
{% block index %}class="active"{% endblock %}
```

***contacts.html***

```html
{%- extends 'base.html' %}
...
{% block contacts %}class="active"{% endblock %}
```

и так далее во всех страницах, которые соответствуют пунктам главного меню сайта

Answer (score 0):

Я во вьюхе задаю некоторую переменную шаблона, а в самом шаблоне ее проверяю:

```
<a class="{%if curr_page == "about"%}active{% endif %}">About</a>
```

Чтобы упростить восприятие, конструкцию можно упихать в макрос:

```
{% macro is_active(label) %}
    {% if label == curr_page %}
        active
    {% else %}
        passive
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

А в ссылке:

```
<a class="{{is_active('about')}}">About</a>
```

Это позволяет самому управлять выделением пунктов меню. Для меня это удобнее, чем напрямую привязываться к адресам страниц.

Comment: Большое спасибо за еще один вариант )